# Filtering Rows from DF with either multiple values

Tags: r

I have a chemistry data frame that is working with cave structure chemical data. Here is a sample of the df.

```
    <Id> <Structure> <ph>
     1    stream      6
     2    tributary   7
     3    seep        4
     4    stream      6
     5    seep        4
     6    tributary   8
     7    pool        10
     8    stream      6
     9    spring      7
     10   speleothem  5
     11   tributary   6
     12   stream      8
```

I am trying to use the `filter()` function in order to only see the data that have structure = stream and tributary.

```
    filter(cave.df, Structure == c("stream","tributary"))
```

But this only returns some of the values and not all. I have checked and it is not an issue of spelling because when I filter them individually I get all the values. Sorry if this is a novice question.

Answer (score 0):

if you try with the next:

```
structure.i <- c("stream","tributary")
cave.df[cave.df$Structure%in%structure.i,]
```

Comment: and then what ?